# Minimum value of $|\sum_i^4 k_i|$ where $k_i$ is complex

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I want to find the minimum value of module of sum of four complex number, $|\sum_i^4 k_i|$, if their phase are arbitrary, and the module of each number is given.

My idea is as following:

For 3 numbers, If three number does not satisfy triangle inequality (giving number 0 in this case), I can try
$$\text{Max}\left(2|k_i| - \sum_n^3 |k_n|\right)$$

That is, using the longest number subtracts two others.

So if I have 4 number, then I should get
$$\text{Max}\left(2|k_i| - \sum_n^4 |k_n|, 2|k_i| - 2|k_j| - \sum_n^4 |k_n| \right)$$
That is, other than the longest number subtracts 3 others, I can also do the sum of two longer number subtracts 2 others.

I wish to know is there a more simple (and more elegant) solution to this problem. And It would be great if anyone come up a general solution for arbitrary many numbers.

This looks like a problem already been solved, but I did not found it on internet (or I searched wrong key works). If anyone have seem this problem before please guide me.

Comment: Why is this equivalent to minimising the sum of $\pm|k_i|$? For instance, if $k_i$ are the three cube roots of $1$, their sum is $0$, but the minimum value of $\pm|k_i|$ is $1$. Perhaps I have misunderstood the question?

Comment: If you take an arbitrary small module, the minimum is zero... ?

Comment: @TonyK You seems right.. I was thinking the min you can get is to fold them in one direction... but I think what I state should be the case if they cannot make a triangle?

Comment: You cannot find the minimum of any set of complex numbers because C is not an ordered field.  Restate your problem correctly.

Comment: @WilliamElliot Sorry, I mean to say to module of the sum

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I think the question is: Given four positive real numbers $r_i$, what is the minimum possible value of $|\sum k_i|$, where each $k_i$ is a complex number with $|k_i|=r_i$?

Comment: @Awoo, "what I state should be the case if they cannot make a triangle": surely you can see by generalising my counter-example that your conjecture must be wrong? For instance, what if they _almost_ make a triangle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r_i=|k_i|$ be the absolute values of the $k_i$. We may assume that $r_1\ge r_2\ge r_3\ge r_4$.

If $r_1>r_2+r_3+r_4$, then the minimum value of $|\sum k_i|$ is $r_1-r_2-r_3-r_4$.

Otherwise, we can rotate $k_3$ and $k_4$ so that $|k_2+k_3+k_4|=r_1$, so the minimum value of $|\sum k_i|$ is $0$. To show this explicitly would involve drawing some pictures and considering various cases, which I'm not going to do. But you might like to try and convince yourself that it's true.

**Updated to add:**

In fact the same is true for any number $n\ge 3$ of points. Proof is by induction, with the inductive hypothesis:

If $(r_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a fixed sequence of positive real numbers with $r_1\ge r_i$ for all $i$, and $(k_i)_{i=1}^n$ is a sequence of complex numbers with $|k_i|=r_i$, then $|\sum k_i|$ can take any value from $\max\,(r_1-\sum_{i=2}^n r_i,\, 0)$ to $\sum_{i=1}^n r_i$.

In particular, the minimum possible value of $|\sum k_i|$ is $\max\,(r_1-\sum_{i=2}^n r_i,\, 0)$.